# python pydub.silence split_on_silence returning 0 chunk

Tags: python

I am using **split_on_silence** function with parameters as shown in below method in python.

I am not getting any single chunk in return. chunks length is 0.

what wrong am I doing?

```
from pydub import AudioSegment 
from pydub.silence import split_on_silence

song = AudioSegment.from_wav(my_file) 
            
# split track where silence is 0.5 seconds  
# or more and get chunks 
chunks = split_on_silence(song, 
    # must be silent for at least 0.5 seconds 
    # or 500 ms. adjust this value based on user 
    # requirement. if the speaker stays silent for  
    # longer, increase this value. else, decrease it. 
    min_silence_len = 500, 
    
    # consider it silent if quieter than -16 dBFS 
    # adjust this per requirement 
    silence_thresh = -16
)
```

Comment: can you share the audio file ?

Comment: This was totally random video converted. So I have nothing to do with its content. :)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZdJxDLGue7WIt0C_nxKRrIgs9OR8JnUX/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
song.dBFS
-22.4691372540001

silence_thresh - (in dBFS) anything quieter than this will be considered silence.Notice the average loudness of the sound is -22.4 dBFS (quieter than 
 the default silence_thresh of -16dBFS).
```

Change the value of `silence_thresh = -23`.

[worked from `silence_thresh = -21`]. check [this](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/169) for further details